# Specified cast is not valid in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Does anyone know what happens when getting an error like Specified cast is not valid? I commented on the line where the error happens

```
private async void GetEmployee()
 {
     var _token = await GetAccessToken();            
     using (var _client = new HttpClient())
     {
         var _uri = "domain here";

         _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_uri);
         _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
         _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);

         var _response = await _client.GetAsync("endpoint here'");

         var Emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(await _response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
         Employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>((IEnumerable<Employee>)Emp); //Im having error on this line
     }
 }

 ObservableCollection<Employee> _employee;
 public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employee
 {
     get
     {
         return _employee;
     }
     set
     {
         _employee = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why would it be allowed to cast a single element to an array of that element? Instead of passing `Emp`, try passing `new[] { Emp }` to the `new ObservableCollection<Employee>` constructor call.

Comment: hi @UweKeim Im new to this what would I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing this:

```cs
Employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>((IEnumerable<Employee>)Emp);
```

to this:

```cs
Employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(new[] {Emp});
```

[See .NET Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7kyfQs).

[See ObservableCollection documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__).

---

The `new[] { ... }` is short for `new Employee[] { ... }` and creates a new array with the initial value(s) inside the `{` and `}`.

[See array documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/).

Comment: Hi @UweKeim I tried it and it works I'm new to programming thank you for helping me :)